# AWS RDS Import/restore SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

How to import SQL server `.bak` file to AWS RDS from `EBS/EFS` volume? Official docs use `S3` for storing `.bak` file, but max file size for `S3` is 5GB. How to use alternative storage locations such as simple `EBS` volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload files larger than five gigabytes to S3 via the [multi-part upload API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html), up to a maximum filesize of 5 terabytes. [From the official S3 FAQs:](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/)

> The total volume of data and number of objects you can store are unlimited. Individual Amazon S3 objects can range in size from a minimum of 0 bytes to a maximum of 5 terabytes. The largest object that can be uploaded in a single PUT is 5 gigabytes.

That's one potential workaround in case you can't figure out how to use EBS/EFS for [RDS Native Backup and Restore.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html)